# Set all checkboxes in listview at the same time

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have the adapter code below which is backed by a multidimensional array. The code is inside a ListFragment which has a parent Activity.

when  a checkbox is selected, I call a listener which sends information to the parent Activity.

All this works fine. My problem is, how can I make a button select/deselect all the checkboxes in the list and send the information in each row to the listener that will send the info to the parent Activity?

I have found the following code that selects all the checkboxed but this doesn't take into account the data in each row that needs to go to the parent Activity.

```
final ListView list = getListView();
    for ( int i=0; i< getListAdapter().getCount(); i++ ) {
            list.setItemChecked(i, true);
    }
private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<?> list;

        boolean[] checkBoxState;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

            super(context, R.layout.rotarowlayout);
            Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;

            checkBoxState = new boolean[this.list.size()];
        //Log.e(TAG, "list has size of " + this.list.size());
        }

        private class ViewHolder
         {

            TextView startTime;
            TextView duration;
            TextView status;
            TextView name;
            TextView actualIn;
            TextView actualOut;
            TextView carerName;
            TextView statusBox;
            ImageView noteStatus;
            ImageView doubleupStatus;
            ImageView timeCritical;

            CheckBox checkBox;
         }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

             if(convertView == null)
                {
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rotarowlayout, null);
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                        viewHolder.startTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowstarttime);
                        viewHolder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowduration);
                        viewHolder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);
                        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientname);
                        viewHolder.noteStatus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notestatus);
                        viewHolder.doubleupStatus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.doubleupstatus);
                        viewHolder.timeCritical = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timecritical);
                        viewHolder.actualIn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientactualin);
                        viewHolder.actualOut = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowclientactualout);
                        viewHolder.carerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowruncarername);
                        viewHolder.statusBox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowstatus);

                        viewHolder.checkBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_checkbox_multi_select_carer);

                         //link the cached views to the convertview
                        convertView.setTag( viewHolder);
                }else
                {             
                   viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               }
            String record = list.get(position).toString();
            convertView.setTag(R.layout.rotarowlayout, record);
            String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");
            Log.e(TAG, "itemin record = " + itemsInRecord.length);
            final String[] recordItem = new String[itemsInRecord.length];

            for (int x = 0; x < itemsInRecord.length; x++) {
                recordItem[x] = itemsInRecord[x];
                Log.e(TAG, "recordItem[x]" + x + " " +recordItem[x] );
            }
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
             viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                    checkBoxState[position] = true;
                   mListener.onMultiSelectUpdateCallSelected("ADD", recordItem[5]);
}else{
 checkBoxState[position] = false;
 mListener.onMultiSelectUpdateCallSelected("REMOVE", recordItem[5]);
}
  }

});
    return convertView;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
if(this.list != null){
return this.list.size();
}else{
 return 0;
 }}
  }// end of adapter class
```

Comment: Have a look on it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553186/android-checkbox-listview-select-all-disable-enable

Comment: @KishuDroid Hi that is the same post i got my code from. unfortunately the accepted answer only works with cursorAdapter. i'm using ArrayAdapter.

Comment: You do not send information to each listener. You only set the wanted values in your multidimensional array. After that call NotifyDataSetChanged on the adapter. Why are you calling `boolean[] checkBoxState;` multidimensional? You only have to set this array and you are done.

Comment: @turtleboy: Please check this link with ArrayAdapter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911361/how-to-get-selected-list-items-from-a-listview-with-checkbox-and-custom-adapter

Comment: @greenapps private final ArrayList<?> list uses the following object to populate it. TwoDimentionalArrayList<String> array; I send the following to the listener. recordItem[5] is a String GUID. mListener.onMultiSelectUpdateCallSelected("ADD", recordItem[5]);