# Scrolling issues with checkboxes in a listview (VB / XAML)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, listview

**Hello ! I'm having trouble with a *Listview* full of *Checkboxes* that check/uncheck themselves when i'm scrolling up and down.**

It seems to be a known problem, and I find a lot of topics with solutions, but only for *Java/Android applications*, as you can see here :
[checkbox unchecked when i scroll listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895763/checkbox-unchecked-when-i-scroll-listview-in-android)

I did not manage to get how the solution works in order to translate it into Visual Basic, so here I am, hoping for some help !

**---------------------- Here is how my program work ----------------------**

I have a DataGrid with certain number of columns. In my Listview, each checkbox is link to a column, in order to show/hide the column when the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

**-> Here is the definition of my Listview in the XAML code :**

1) *In the window resources* :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Check_Template">
        <CheckBox Name="checkbox" Content="{Binding sL_Name}" Click="CheckBox_Click_1" IsChecked="True"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

2) *In the window definition* :

```
<ListView x:Name="Colum_Select" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Check_Template}" />
```

**-> When the window is loaded :**

```
'Creation of a list which will get the headers of the datagrid columns  

Dim L_View As New List(Of L_class)
For Each prop In MyDataGrid.Columns
    L_View.Add(New L_class(prop.Header.ToString))
Next

'Send them to the Listview in my XAML code  

Colum_Select.ItemsSource = L_View
```

**-> The definition of my L_class which will get my column headers :**

```
Class L_class

    Public L_Name As String

    Sub New(One As String)
        L_Name = One
    End Sub

    Public Property sL_Name() As String
        Get
            Return L_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            L_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**-> The result :**

[My Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSZWf.png)

**-> Here is the VB fonction called when a checkbox is check/unchecked :**

```
Private Sub CheckBox_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    'Get the checkbox which fires the event
    Dim senderCB As CheckBox = sender

    'Find the column in my datagrid that correspond with the checkbox
    Dim item As Object = FindName(senderCB.Content.ToString)
    Dim col As DataGridColumn = item

    'Hide/Show this column
    If (senderCB.IsChecked = True) Then
        col.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    Else
        col.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of this bug : the state of the checkbutton must be define in the VB code, not in the XAML ! Here is how i proceeded.

In the window ressources, I binded the `IsChecked` property ...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Check_Template">
        <CheckBox Name="checkbox" Content="{Binding sL_Name}" Click="CheckBox_Click_1" IsChecked="{Binding sL_Check}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

... to the correspondant property in my `L_Class` ...

```
Class L_class

Public L_Name As String
Public L_Check As Boolean

Sub New(One As String, Two As Boolean)
    L_Name = One
    L_Check = Two
End Sub

Public Property sL_Name() As String
    Get
        Return L_Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        L_Name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property sL_Check() As Boolean
    Get
        Return L_Check
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        L_Check = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

... and then adapt the code when the window load :

```
    Dim L_View As New List(Of L_class)

    For Each prop In ResultatSQLDataGrid.Columns
        L_View.Add(New L_class(prop.Header.ToString, True))
    Next

    Colum_Select.ItemsSource = L_View
```

And no more auto-checking when scrolling in my case.

Hoping my monologue will be of some help. Cheers !