# ToggleButton in ListView being inconsistent with isChecked setting

Tags: android, listview

So I have a button set in a listview to save in sharedpreferences its checked state when checked/unchecked and then when it's loading the view it'll automatically set the check state based on whether it's saved-as checked or un-checked, but some seem to un-check themselves or never toggle at all. It's fairly inconsistent.

Here's my ListViewAdapter

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View ListItem = convertView;
        Holder holder;

        if (ListItem == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            ListItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new Holder();
    //            holder.description = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityDesc);
                holder.banner = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityBanner);
                holder.website = (Button) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityWebsite);
                holder.active = (ToggleButton) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.isActiveButtonToggle);
    //            holder.background = (RelativeLayout) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.listItemBG);
                holder.highlight =  (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.highlight);
    //            holder.highlight2 = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.highlight2);
                holder.title = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.titleText);

            ListItem.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (Holder) ListItem.getTag();
        }
        final deities deity = data[position];
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        deity.active = sharedPref.getBoolean(Integer.toString(deity.id), false);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        View.OnClickListener holderListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.webView);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webView.loadUrl(deity.url);
            }
        };

        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener ToggleButtonListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                int position = (int) buttonView.getParent().getT();
//                deities deity = data[position];
                deity.active = isChecked;
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = sharedPref.edit();
                TextView deityActiveCount = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.deitySelectedCounter);
                final CompoundButton Button = buttonView;
                final RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) ((ViewGroup) Button.getParent()).getParent();
                prefeditor.putBoolean(Integer.toString(deity.id), isChecked);
                prefeditor.apply();
                setCounter(isChecked ? getCounter() + 1 : getCounter() - 1);
                ViewGroup ListItem = (ViewGroup) buttonView.getParent();
                int startColor = isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a") : Color.parseColor("#2e7d32");
                int endColor = isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#2e7d32") : Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a");
                ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), startColor, endColor);
                    colorAnimation.setDuration(100);
                    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                            ImageView sideThing1 = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.highlight);
//                            ImageView sideThing2 = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.highlight2);
                            sideThing1.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
//                            sideThing2.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                            Button.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());

                        }
                    });
                colorAnimation.start();
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };


        if (deity.active) {
            holder.active.setChecked(true);
            holder.active.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));
            holder.highlight.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));
//            holder.highlight2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));


        } else {
            holder.active.setChecked(false);
            holder.active.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
            holder.highlight.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
//            holder.highlight2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
        }


        holder.active.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ToggleButtonListener);
        holder.website.setOnClickListener(holderListener);
        holder.banner.setImageResource(deity.banner);
//        holder.description.setText(deity.description);
        holder.banner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
//        holder.description.setText(deity.url);
        holder.title.setText(deity.title + " " + deity.active);
        return ListItem;

    }
```

[This is what I mean by inconsistent (click me, it's a video)](https://my.mixtape.moe/yugvbb.mp4)

Notice how some revert back/don't save?

A day later, I still can't figure it out.

Comment: The data itself does not get updated. where are you calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I would suggest to remove the OnCheckedChangeListener, make the CompoundButton clickable false and handle it through a on item click on the list

Comment: oh boy, that's what I was missing! Thanks. If you post it as a solution I'll be happy to give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Make sure your ToggleButton's setOnCheckedChangedListener is set **before** calling setChecked. [This issue is talked about more here (click me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895763/checkbox-unchecked-when-i-scroll-listview-in-android).

To fix this specific issue (although thanks zombie for pointing out notifyDataSetChanged's importance), I moved

`holder.active.setOnCheckedChangedListener(ToggleButtonListener);`

to before

```
holder.active.setChecked(diety.active);
```

since apparently this is a common issue with ListViews, where onChecked doesn't work properly if the listener is infront of setChecked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View ListItem = convertView;
    Holder holder;

    if (ListItem == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        ListItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder();
        //            holder.description = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityDesc);
        holder.banner = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityBanner);
        holder.website = (Button) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.deityWebsite);
        holder.active = (ToggleButton) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.isActiveButtonToggle);
        //            holder.background = (RelativeLayout) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.listItemBG);
        holder.highlight = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.highlight);
        //            holder.highlight2 = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.highlight2);
        holder.title = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.titleText);

        ListItem.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (Holder) ListItem.getTag();
    }
    final deities deity = data[position];

    View.OnClickListener holderListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WebView webView = (WebView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.loadUrl(deity.url);
        }
    };

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener ToggleButtonListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            int position = (int) buttonView.getTag();

            final deities deity = data[position];

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = sharedPref.edit();
            final CompoundButton Button = buttonView;
            final RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) Button.getParent().getParent();

            deity.active = isChecked;
            prefeditor.putBoolean(Integer.toString(deity.id), isChecked);
            prefeditor.apply();

            int startColor = isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a") : Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a");
            int endColor = isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#2e7d32") : Color.parseColor("#2e7d32");

            ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), startColor, endColor);
            colorAnimation.setDuration(100);
            colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                    ImageView sideThing1 = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.highlight);
                    //                            ImageView sideThing2 = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.highlight2);
                    sideThing1.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                    //                            sideThing2.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                    Button.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());

                }
            });
            colorAnimation.start();

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    deity.active = sharedPref.getBoolean(Integer.toString(deity.id), false);

    holder.active.setChecked(deity.active);

    if (deity.active) {
        holder.active.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));
        holder.highlight.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));
    } else {
        holder.active.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
        holder.highlight.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
    }

    holder.active.setTag(position);

    holder.active.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ToggleButtonListener);
    holder.website.setOnClickListener(holderListener);
    holder.banner.setImageResource(deity.banner);
    //        holder.description.setText(deity.description);
    holder.banner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
    //        holder.description.setText(deity.url);
    holder.title.setText(deity.title + " " + deity.active);
    return ListItem;
}
```

PS: I tried to fix the problem without a lot of changes so this might not be the best answer

Comment: Thanks. Thanks especially for showing my obvious mistake of making an if statement for the true/false isChecked thing, I really don't know why I did that

Comment: So, by using the declaration of position/diety in the getView method I've been getting crashes for attempting to invoke Integer.intValue() on a null object reference. also for some weird reason my notifyDataSetChanged stopped fixing the problem and it's broke again. I've updated OP