# resets all Widgets when scrolling up and down?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

**when ever i move down scroll the widgets refresh . i need to stop refresh**

when ever i move down scroll the widgets refresh . i need to stop refresh. the valus of widgets shuld be remain till image button clicked. 
 after change values of widgets when i scroll up after down the widgets values reset . the values should be remain as i perform action.
[this is refreshing widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moe7E.gif)
**XML file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:textColor="#000"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_Lt"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Teacher_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColor="#000"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_teacher_name"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_teacher_name"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp">
</Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/radioButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioButton_group_PresentAbsent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_present"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="Present"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton_absent"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="Absent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtStartTimePicker"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:text="LATE"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtEndTimePicker"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:text="LEAVE"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/submit_Attendance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/biit"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

after change values of widgets when i scroll up after down the widgets values reset , please help . the values should be remain as i perform action.
**Java File**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String[] class_room;
    Context context;
    String[] teacher_name;
    String[] days;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    public CustomAdapter(teacher_attendance mainActivity, String[] arr, String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        class_room = arr;
        teacher_name = arr1;
        days=arr2;
        context = mainActivity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return class_room.length
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        holder.radioButton_Group_PresentAbsent = (RadioGroup) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_group_PresentAbsent);
        holder.radioButtonPresent = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_present);
        holder.txtlt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_Lt);
        holder.txtteacher = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_teacher_name);
        holder.radioButtonAbsent = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_absent);
        holder.etxtStart_time_Picker = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.etxtStartTimePicker);
        holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setFocusable(false);
        holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.etxtEndTimePicker);
        holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setFocusable(false);
        holder.txtlt.setText(class_room[position]);
        holder.txtteacher.setText(teacher_name[position]);
        holder.submitAttendance = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.submit_Attendance);
        holder.submitAttendance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.spinner_teacher_name = (Spinner) rowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_teacher_name);
        arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, teacher_name);
        arrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.spinner_teacher_name.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
        holder.submitAttendance.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String teacherName, status = null, startTime, endTime;
                holder.dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(v.getContext());

                startTime = holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.getText().toString();
                endTime = holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.getText().toString();
                teacherName = holder.txtteacher.getText().toString();
                if (holder.radioButtonPresent.isChecked()) {
                    status = holder.radioButtonPresent.getText().toString();
                    holder.dataBaseHelper.insertData(teacherName, status, startTime, endTime);
                    Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), teacher_name[position] + " is " + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (holder.radioButtonAbsent.isChecked()) {
                    status = holder.radioButtonAbsent.getText().toString();
                    holder.dataBaseHelper.insertData(teacherName, status, startTime, endTime);
                    Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), teacher_name[position] + " is " + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), "Teacher Status is not Mark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.spinner_teacher_name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                for (int a = 0; a < position; a++) {
                    holder.txtteacher.setText(teacher_name[position]);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.radioButtonPresent.setChecked(true);
                    holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tim = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute);
                    }
                };
                new TimePickerDialog(context, tim, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
                holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tim = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute);
                    }
                };
                new TimePickerDialog(context, tim, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
            }
        });

        holder.radioButtonAbsent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (holder.radioButtonAbsent.isChecked())
                {
                    holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else if (holder.radioButtonPresent.isChecked()) {
                    holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.radioButtonPresent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (holder.radioButtonPresent.isChecked()) {
                    holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (holder.radioButtonAbsent.isChecked()) {
                    holder.etxtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.etxtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView txtlt, txtteacher;
        RadioButton radioButtonPresent, radioButtonAbsent;
        EditText etxtStart_time_Picker,etxtEnd_time_Picker;
        Spinner spinner_teacher_name, spinnerDays;
        ImageButton submitAttendance;
        RadioGroup radioButton_Group_PresentAbsent;
        DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I read a blog to get help for my problem i have got. i want to share link where from i got help [from this link](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

and i got this reference form [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895763/checkbox-unchecked-when-i-scroll-listview-in-android)

### Answer

this class is CustomAdapter and it is extends BaseAdapter

```
Holder holder = new Holder();
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        final View rowView;
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        holder.radioButton_Group_PresentAbsent = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_group_PresentAbsent);
        holder.radioButtonPresent = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_present);
        holder.txtlt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_Lt);
        holder.txtteacher = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_teacher_name);
        holder.radioButtonAbsent = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_absent);
        holder.txtStart_time_Picker = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtStartTimePicker);
        holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setFocusable(false);
        holder.txtEnd_time_Picker = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtEndTimePicker);
        holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setFocusable(false);
        holder.txtlt.setText(class_room[position]);
        holder.txtteacher.setText(teacher_name[position]);
        holder.submitAttendance = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.submit_Attendance);
        holder.submitAttendance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.spinner_teacher_name = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_teacher_name);
        arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, teacher_name);
        arrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.spinner_teacher_name.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

        holder.submitAttendance.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String teacherName, status = null, startTime, endTime;
                holder.dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(v.getContext());

                startTime = holder.txtStart_time_Picker.getText().toString();
                endTime = holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.getText().toString();
                teacherName = holder.txtteacher.getText().toString();
                DataBaseHelper ds = new DataBaseHelper(context);

                if (holder.radioButtonPresent.isChecked()) {
                    status = holder.radioButtonPresent.getText().toString();
                    holder.dataBaseHelper.insertData(teacherName, status, startTime, endTime);
                    Toast.makeText(context, teacher_name[position] + " is " + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (holder.radioButtonAbsent.isChecked()) {
                    status = holder.radioButtonAbsent.getText().toString();
                    holder.dataBaseHelper.insertData(teacherName, status, startTime, endTime);
                    Toast.makeText(context, teacher_name[position] + " is " + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Teacher Status is not Mark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.spinner_teacher_name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                for (int a = 0; a < position; a++) {
                    holder.txtteacher.setText(teacher_name[position]);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.radioButtonPresent.setChecked(true);
                    holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tim = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute);
                    }
                };
                new TimePickerDialog(context, tim, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

                holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener tim = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute);
                    }
                };
                new TimePickerDialog(context, tim, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

            }
        });

        holder.radioButtonAbsent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.radioButtonAbsent.isChecked()) {
                    holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else if (holder.radioButtonPresent.isChecked()) {
                    holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.radioButtonPresent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.radioButtonPresent.isChecked()) {
                    holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (holder.radioButtonAbsent.isChecked()) {
                    holder.txtStart_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txtEnd_time_Picker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.spinner_teacher_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txtteacher.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.radioButton_group_PresentAbsent, holder.radioButton_Group_PresentAbsent);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.radioButton_present, holder.radioButtonPresent);

        convertView.setTag(R.id.text_Lt, holder.txtlt);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.radioButton_present, holder.radioButtonPresent);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.text_teacher_name, holder.txtteacher);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.radioButton_absent, holder.radioButtonAbsent);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtStartTimePicker, holder.txtStart_time_Picker);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtEndTimePicker, holder.txtEnd_time_Picker);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.submit_Attendance, holder.submitAttendance);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.spinner_teacher_name, holder.spinner_teacher_name);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.radioButtonPresent.setTag(position);
    holder.radioButtonAbsent.setTag(position);

    return convertView;
}
public class Holder
{
    protected TextView txtlt, txtteacher;
    RadioButton radioButtonPresent, radioButtonAbsent;
    TextView txtStart_time_Picker,txtEnd_time_Picker;
    Spinner spinner_teacher_name, spinnerDays;
    ImageButton submitAttendance;
    RadioGroup radioButton_Group_PresentAbsent;
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
}
```

i work very hard to get this solution finally i got now i want to share on this website cause i also got lot of solutions form this website.